# Show that $e^x+e^{-x} \geq e^0+e^0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Here we have to prove that $e^x+e^{-x} \geq e^0+e^0$

I'm pretty confused and stuck.

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate $e^0$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\cosh x$?

Comment: There is a famous inequality that says that "$a + 1/a \geq$ _something_" always holds for positive $a$. Do you know what that _something_ is, and how to prove it?

Comment: No sorry I don't... I only know that e^0=1

Comment: @Skoutas The AM-GM inequality $\frac{a+b}{2} \ge \sqrt{ab}$ for positive $a,b$.

Comment: So could please tell me how will I write this as a final?

Comment: @Skoutas $e^x + e^{-x} = 2 \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2} \geq 2 \sqrt{e^x e^{-x}} = 2 \sqrt{1} = 2$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x) = e^x+e^{-x}$. There is only one stationary point of this function on the real line since

$${df \over dx}(x) = e^x - e^{-x}=0$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow x=-x \Leftrightarrow x =0 $$

and ${d^2f \over dx^2}(0) = f(0) = 2 \geq 0$, so that $f$ has its global minimum at $x=0$ so that $f(x) \geq f(0)$. In other words, $e^x + e^{-x} \geq e^0 + e^{0}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $e^x=u$ thus inequality becomes $u+\frac{1}{u}\geq 2$ thus $(u-1)^2\geq 0$ thus its easily known that a square is always positive with minimum value of $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's rearrange the inequality with equivalent transformations on both sides, which does not change its truth value (i.e., if the inequality is true it will remain true, and vice versa).
\begin{align*}
e^x + e^{-x} &\geq 2 \\
e^x -2 + e^{-x} &\geq 0 \\
(e^{x/2})^2 -2 + (e^{-x/2})^2 &\geq 0 \\
(e^{x/2} - e^{-x/2})^2 &\geq 0
\end{align*}
And the square of any real number is indeed positive $\Rightarrow$ the last inequality is true. However, it still bares the same truth value as the inital inequality $\Rightarrow$ the initial inequality is true as well. In the process, we used $e^{x/2} \cdot e^{-x/2} = 1$.

Comment: Why would any tomfool downvote this answer? Are binomals too revolutionary these days?

Comment: I really don't know!

Comment: You've assumed what you were trying to prove.

Comment: @user320276 No! I applied equivalent transformations to the inequality (i.e., they do not change the truth value) in order to put it to a form where it is clear that the inequality is *true*, and therefore the intial inequality is *true* because it has the same truth value. Learn the basics please.

Comment: @GDumphart You may want to add that these transformations do not change the truth values. You must be careful with manipulations like these. Furthermore, the tone of the last sentence is kind of condescending to someone who, presumably, is just trying to help.

Comment: @zz20s I did so in my previous comment. You are right that the answer to an intro course question should probably hold some more meta information. Sorry, it's just annoying to get downvoted from pre-calculus people because of misconceptions. I guess I'll just dodge these questions in the future.

Comment: To avoid any confusion, you could also write your answer as follow:
$$e^{x}+e^{-x}-2 = (e^{x/2})^2+(e^{-x/2})^2+2e^{x}e^{-x}=(e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2})^2\geq 0$$

Comment: @GDumphart I think you should answers these questions, because your answer is very good. I'm pretty sure you're using $AM-GM$, you could clarify your post by just noting this.

Comment: @AndresMejia Well, you really have to look for the AM-GM. This answer is nice because it's basically using $(a+b)^2 =a^2+2ab+b^2$ in a clever way.

Comment: that's a good point. I  only see that justification in the way you wrote it. Otherwise, the first inequality seems unmotivated.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive feedback guys, I implemented it in my answer. No Andres, I did not explicitly use AM-GM.

Comment: Okay! A good answer. All the best

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to use a series argument to prove that $e^x+e^{-x} \geq 2=e^0+e^0$

First, note that $$2\cosh x=e^x+e^{-x}.$$

Now, recall that $$\cosh x = 1 + \frac {x^2} {2!} + \frac {x^4} {4!} + \frac {x^6} {6!} + \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Thus, $$e^x+e^{-x}=2\cosh x = 2 + \frac {2x^2} {2!} + \frac {2x^4} {4!} + \frac {2x^6} {6!} + \cdots $$

All of the terms after the first are positive for any $x$ since the powers are even.

Thus, $$e^x+e^{-x}=2\cosh x = 2 + \frac {2x^2} {2!} + \frac {2x^4} {4!} + \frac {2x^6} {6!} + \cdots  \geq2$$